# Insert in to DB if input doesn't fall within a range

Tags: c#, sql, linq

As a input i am getting  startDate and endDate. I have to do a linq query from client side to check if there is any existing entry in DB within this time.

For example, in my DB if i have an entry with StartDate of 2018-01-05 and enddate of 2018-01-09 and user tries to put another entry with start date of 2018-01-04 and enddate of 2018-01-06 i should not allow that, because in my DB i have already an entry that is common within this time range. Here is my code

```
 var stDate = dbcontext.tables.Where( st => 
                             st.StartDate <= UserStartDate && st.EndDate >= UserEndDate && st.Status == "Queued" ||
                             st.StartDate >= UserStartDate && st.EndDate >= UserEndDate && st.Status == "Queued" ||
                             st.StartDate <= UserStartDate && st.EndDate <= UserEndDate && st.Status == "Queued" ||
                             st.StartDate >= UserStartDate && st.EndDate <= UserEndDate && st.Status == "Queued").ToList();
                if (stDate.Count >0 )
                {
                    //notification to user("There is an existing request within this time range");
                }
                else
                {
                    // do the rest operation
                }
```

But the problem is if someone tries to enter an entry from 2018-01-09 to 2018-01-10 it falls under 3 condition and application is not taking this entry.
Any suggestion for me how can i improve my code?

Comment: I would always do filtering/checking like that in the Query itself. Retreiving the Data to your client to do filtering/checks there is asking to get issues liek Race conditoins, excessive Network load and what not. As for "find if data is within range" problem, that is a problem that vexes me too.

Comment: Can you check `.Status` of this range?

Comment: I don't think there can be any date range that doesn't fall in these conditions.

Comment: You are right @FaizanRabbani, do you have any idea how can i allow user to input if their start and end date dosent fall in to the existing entry. .Staus i have to use Queued because there might my other entry within same time range but in different status. I am not concern about those status.

Comment: @Shaif Do you only want both start and end to don't fall in existing range? Are these ranges okay: `2018-01-08` & `2018-01-15`
`2018-01-02` & `2018-01-07` `2018-01-01` & `2018-01-15`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your logic is a bit off. In all of your conditions, you compare `StartDate` to `UserStartDate` and `EndDate` to `UserEndDate`. Instead, you should be comparing the same thing in each condition. See below:

```
var stDate = dbcontext.tables
             .Where(st =>  st.Status == "Queued" 
               && (  st.StartDate >= UserStartDate && st.StartDate < UserEndDate   
                  || st.StartDate > UserStartDate  && st.StartDate <= UserEndDate  
                  || st.EndDate >= UserStartDate   && st.EndDate < UserEndDate     
                  || st.EndDate > UserStartDate    && st.EndDate <= UserEndDate )
              ).ToList();
```

Notice that the `StartDate` is compared to both `UserStartDate` and `UserEndDate`in the top 2 conditions and the `EndDate` is compared to both `UserStartDate` and `UserEndDate`in the bottom 2 conditions.

> i should not allow that, because in my DB i have already an entry that is common within this time range.

That means that the only conditions you are worried about is if the `UserStartDate` and `UserEndDate` are on opposite sides of either your `StartDate` or `EndDate` as shown below.

[image]

If Either of these conditions are met, you will always be within the same date range.

**Update:**

The code above was updated as the OP indicated that the `UserStartDate` could actually be the same as the `EndDate` or the `UserEndDate` could be the same as the `StartDate` but don't count as overlapping data.

**Update2:**

As the OP pointed out, I forgot about the case where both the `UserStartDate` and `UserEndDate` were within the date range. Per the OP's comment, that line is the following:

```
st.StartDate <= UserStartDate && st.EndDate >= User.EndDate && st.Status == "Queued"
```

Comment: Than you @Sudsy1002 but the problem if i follow your code user can't create entry for start and end date lesser then DB. for example if someone try to add an entry 2018-01-04 to 2018-01-05 it will prevent them

Comment: @Shaif I've editted so that the `StartDate` can be the same value as the `UserEndDate` and the `EndDate` can be the same value as the `UserStartDate` but cannot satisfy both (as that would result in overlapping data).

Comment: You should use `.Any()` instead of `.ToList()` and a `.Count>0` afterwards for performance reasons, though.
This way in a case where there are lots of lines in the DB you don't get millions of matches.

Comment: Thank you so much @Sudsy1002 . Problem resolved. I have just added another check point for not to allow user add entry within the rime range.  `st.StartDate <= UserStartDate && st.EndDate >= User.EndDate && st.Status == "Queued"`

Comment: @Shaif And thank you for your coment. Answer updated.